# Display fullscreen view controller from UIInputViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, keyboard, ios8-extension, uiinputviewcontroller

I'm currently building a custom keyboard for iOS 8 though extensions. When the user presses a certain button on the keyboard view, I want to present a full screen modal view controller. When I try to present the view controller, it tries to present within the bounds of the keyboard view. I'm using `[self presentViewController:animated:completion:]` with an instantiated view controller. Is there anyway to present a full screen view controller? akin to photo editing extensions(which display a full screen view controller)

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean "present a full screen view controller?"  Does the frame of the view controller you're presenting not match the frame of the window?

Answer (score 3):

You should Increase height of your keyboard and then present your View Controller. Try something like this:

```
- (void) presentVC{
         NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:nil
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                        multiplier:1.0
                                                          constant:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height];

        [self.view addConstraint: _heightConstraint];

        TestViewController *test = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:test animated:YES completion:^{

        }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to present your viewController from the controller that called the keyboard, not from the keyboard itself.

Try:

```
[self.parentViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]
```

Comment: I tried that too, with no avail :/ UIInputViewController(the keyboard) simply refuses to present a full screen view controller it seems....

Comment: Dismiss the keyboard, present your view controller, do what you have to do, dismiss it and show the keyboard again

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question...I'm building a custom keyboard and this is going to be in other applications throughout the system. This means that I can't dismiss the keyboard and execute code.

Comment: Maybe you could try to add a subview to your keyboard with the frame of the window. (Don't forget to [keyboard setClipsToBounds:No])